# how to fetch returned data by pdo multi query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i can do this query successfuly in phpmyadmin sql. but when i do this by pdo recive this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error in D:\xampp1\htdocs\admin\feak.php:15 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp1\htdocs\admin\feak.php(15): PDOStatement->fetchObject() #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp1\htdocs\admin\feak.php on line 15

```
include("inclode/class.inc.php");
$con = new connection();
$con->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);
$stmt = $con->con->prepare("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Basket(temporary_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,ArtistName VARCHAR( 20 ),NAMEOfTheDVD VARCHAR( 30 ));INSERT INTO Basket( ArtistName, NAMEOfTheDVD) VALUES ( 'R', 'SHAWooSHANK');SELECT * FROM Basket;");
$stmt->execute();
while($fetch = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
    echo $fetch->NAMEOfTheDVD;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you want to run all these queries in in a single call?

Comment: The query will not run the table will be deleted Tempe

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you just said.

Comment: What exactly are u trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to solve the problem of export  by fetchObject

Comment: run your queries in separate query() calls. The problem solved